# Почему возникает EOF?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import turtle

def convScale(cl,ch,rl,rh,c):
    d = (abs(rl)+abs(rh))/(abs(cl)+abs(ch))
    if not rh-1 > rl-1:
        d = -d
    return rl+d*c
    
def angleToAccel(a):
    ax = ay = 0
    if a >= 0 and a <= 90:
        ax = convScale(0,90,1,0,a)
        ay = convScale(0,90,0,1,a)
    elif a >= 90 and a <= 180:
        ax = convScale(90,180,0,-1,a)
        ay = convScale(90,180,1,0,a)
    elif a >= 180 and a <= 270:
        ax = convScale(180,270,-1,0,a)
        ay = convScale(180,270,0,-1,a)
    elif a >= 270 and a <= 360:
        ax = convScale(270,360,0,1,a)
        ay = convScale(270,360,-1,0,a)
    return ax, ay

f = r = a = v = x = y = 0
p = []

f,r,a,v = map(float, input("f,r,a,v? ").split())

while True:
    p.append((x,y))
    if v <= 0:
        break
    if a > 360:
        a -= 360
    elif a < 0:
        a += 360
    v -= f
    a -= f*2
    if x <= 0:
        v += r*2
        a += r**2
    ax, ay = angleToAccel(a)
    x += ax*v
    y += ay*v
    
for n in p:
    turtle.goto(n[0],n[1])
```

Вот такой несложный код даёт EOF на линии 28 (Traceback (most recent call last): File"/storage/emulated/0/py/ball.py",line 28, in 
f,r,a,v = map(float, input("f,r,a,v? ").split())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line) Я так и не нашёл синтаксических ошибок, и совсем не понимаю отчего она возникает. Возможно связано с тем что программа написана на телефоне, и у редактора иногда проблемы с индентацией и библиотеками. Как избежать этой ошибки?

Comment: т.е. мы должны вручную отсчитать 27 строк?

Comment: ну просто в школе не учат уже даже считать.

Comment: Поправка, 28. Трейс добавил.

Comment: А ввод чисел через запятую, как в подсказке? Тогда и сплит нужно делать по запятой

Comment: Нет, пробел. А даже если так то еол с этим не связан.

Comment: Я предполагаю, что программа запускается вообще без консоли, и при попытке оттуда что-то прочитать просто вылетает ошибка.

Comment: Как тогда "отложить" запуск черепахи/матплотлиба до введения данных в консоль?

Comment: Без понятия, как оно на телефоне работает. Можно попробовать импорт перенести ниже input

Comment: Уберите перенаправление ввода из файла в настройках IDE откуда запускать код пытаетесь или создайте этот файл откуда IDE пытается данные забирать и введите в него данные